# Place a dot before a letter

Tags: r, regex, substring, subset

I need to put a dot before a letter in this type of strings

name of data set: V2

`6K102
62D102
627Z102`

I would like to get this:

`6.K102
62.D102
627.Z102`

I am using this regex:

```
mutate(V2 = gsub("^[A-Z]",'\\.', V2))
```

Comment: what hole stary, `7777` or `KKKK` or `KK77LL` or `7K8J9` or ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string has to start with 1 or more digits followed by a char A-Z, you could use 2 capturing groups

```
^(\d+)([A-Z])
```

In the replacement use `"\\1.\\2"`

```
sub("^([0-9]+)([A-Z])", "\\1.\\2", V2)
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use `sub("([A-Z])",".\\1", V2)`

Answer (score 0):

**This apply to the question before it was updated**.

Usually `\u2022` prints a bullet in text items. So if your question is regarding a `label`, you may just inserted it there *"\u2022 ..."*

Otherwise, for text items in datasets such as `V2`, you can work around by applying `paste0` in combination with `ifelse`. In this case, your text items the you need a black dot infront if, is stored in `V2$name`

```
V2$name <- ifelse(V2$name==1,1,paste0("\u2022", V2$name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex lacks a capturing group around the letter pattern (so that you could keep it after replacement) and contains a redundant `^` anchor that matches the string start location. Also, you are using a `gsub` function while you just need a `sub`, since only one replacement is expected.

Use

```
sub("([[:upper:]])", ".\\1", V2)
```

With `stringr` (see [demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8xIwUZXIVlDyczb0MBISUfJzMgFxjCPArE0uYpLijLz0ousrICM@KLUgpzE5FSNMCMdBaXoaKvSgoLUIqvYWCUgNyZGLybGQEnz/38A)):

```
stringr::str_replace(V2, "[[:upper:]]", "\\.\\0")
```

**Details**

- `sub` - only the first match is replaced
- `([[:upper:]])` - matches and *captures* any uppercase letter into Group 1 (later referenced to with `\1` from the replacement pattern)
- `\1` - the value of Group 1 (the uppercase letter matched)

Note that `stingr` solution uses `\0`, the placeholder for the whole match value, so no need to capture the uppercase letter in the regex pattern.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/jUBIxE):

```
V2 <- c("6K102","62D102","627Z102")
sub("([[:upper:]])", ".\\1", V2)
# => [1] "6.K102"   "62.D102"  "627.Z102"
```